# Ruby retrieve json object, query

Tags: jquery, ruby, json, hash

So I have this model Foo with nested fields,

```
<id: 1, name: "blah", condition: "{\"condition_type\":\"BAR\",\"number\":\"1\""\}">
```

I want to get the list of Foos with condition type Bar only.
I have tried

```
    JSON.parse(Foo.select(:condition)).where({"condition_type"=>"BAR"})
```

but doesn't work. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a slight syntax error in your JSON (I think an extra quote at the end but at the end of `JSON.parse(Foo.select(:condition))` you're now working with a JSON object (which I think you're aware of.  If you were to say:

`JSON.parse(Foo.select(:condition)).class` you would get a hash.

```
[12] pry(main)> json
=> {"condition_type"=>"BAR", "number"=>"1"}
[13] pry(main)> json.class
=> Hash
```

That all said, you can use the the `Enumerable#keep_if` method like this on a `hash`:

```
[26] pry(main)> json = JSON.parse(condition)
=> {"condition_type"=>"BAR", "number"=>"1"}
[27] pry(main)> json.keep_if { |k, v| k == "condition_type" && v == "BAR" }
=> {"condition_type"=>"BAR"}
```

The combined method would look like this:

```
JSON.parse(Foo.select(:condition)).keep_if { |k, v| k == "condition_type" && v == "BAR" }
```

Comment: thanks a lot it helped!! but I was wondering if there is any simpler way of doing it without using blocks, just by using query commands.

Comment: are you storing the json as a text field in your database? If so what database?